# How to explain punctuation in these 3 cases?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes

I had a test task for the position of freelance writer for [sewing](https://sewingland.org) website. I did the writing part, but they asked me to explain some points in my text. How can I prove punctuation in a), b) and c) cases?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apart from **c**, at which point I would probably use a colon or start a fresh sentence instead of using the dash and correct the spelling error so that 'resized' becomes 'resizer'  I can't see a problem. They might prefer 'said' to 'mentioned' at **a** in which case you could drop the second 'that' and the comma underlined at **b** but these are a matter of preferred style which you can only get from extensive viewing of the website or from a style or writing standards manual which they may or may not provide. Sorry, can't be of any more help than that.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is understood as

> Many users mentioned that the budget friendly price makes this software attractive for beginners, and *[many users mentioned]* that you get a lot for your money since it features 25 built-in lettering fonts and five monogramming fonts.

*“that the budget friendly price makes this software attractive for beginners”* is a noun clause (a content clause) and is the object of “mentioned”

*“that you get a lot for your money since it features 25 built-in lettering fonts and five monogramming fonts”* is also a noun clause (a content clause) and is also the object of “mentioned”

You can reduce the whole sentence to *“Many users mentioned A and B.”*

You will note that there is no comma following “A”, however there is one following “beginners”.  That comma is not required but it is inserted as a “pause” comma to aid reading because the first object clause is quite long.

The dash between “software” and “a simple” could be replaced by a full stop, a colon or a semicolon – it is conjunctive but a comma would be wrong as it would result in a comma splice.